# Scheduling Gantt Chart

Tags: python, plot, scheduling, gantt-chart

I'm trying to create a Gantt Chart for 10 machines and 100 Jobs but I have not found how to get something like this

[image: 1]

I just get something like project charts but i don't need that format.

[image: 2]

I found this guide but if I have many machines it will turn so large to do.
https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/how-to-make-gantt-chart-in-python-matplotlib

And my chart now is based on this code
`fig = ff.create_gantt(df, index_col = 'Resource',  bar_width = 0.4, show_colorbar=True) fig.update_layout(xaxis_type='linear', autosize=False, width=800, height=400) fig.show() plot(fig)`

But just appears activities as stairs, and I need "Resource" in Y axis